# html5 form submit sending date with patten yyyy-MM-dd

Tags: java, html, date, spring-mvc, jsp

`form` submit sending `date` with patten `yyyy-MM-dd` to backend on submit. but is there is way to send the date in `dd-MM-yyyy`. I am using `html5`

this works correctly if change `type="text"` than `type="date"`

I am trying to send date `dd-MM-yyyy`, the frontend looks like below.

[image]

On submit, since the value sent to back end is `yyyy-MM-dd` and due to which the following error is happening. *Is there something wrong with my code?*

> 2018-11-16 18:12:20.553  WARN 8925 --- [nio-8080-exec-2]
>   .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Failed to bind request
>   element:
>   org.springframework.web.method.annotation.MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException:
>   Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type
>   'java.time.LocalDate'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to
>   convert from type [java.lang.String] to type
>   [@org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam
>   @org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat
>   java.time.LocalDate] for value '2018-11-09'; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parse attempt failed for value
>   [2018-11-09]

The below is code:

**jsp:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<html lang="en">
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
    href="webjars/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<!-- 
    <spring:url value="/css/main.css" var="springCss" />
    <link href="${springCss}" rel="stylesheet" />
     -->
<c:url value="/css/main.css" var="jstlCss" />
<link href="${jstlCss}" rel="stylesheet" />

</head>
<body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Spring Boot</a>
            </div>
            <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="container">

        <div class="starter-template">
            <h1>Spring Boot Web JSP Example</h1>
            <h2>Message: ${message}</h2>
            <form action="/get" method="post"> 
            <input type="date" name="date" pattern="\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4}"><!--   -->
            <input type="submit" value="submit">
            </form>
        </div>

    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->

    <script type="text/javascript"
        src="webjars/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

**Controller class:**

```
@Controller
public class MyController {

    // inject via application.properties
    @Value("${welcome.message:test}")
    private String message = "Hello World";

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String welcome(Map<String, Object> model) {
        model.put("message", this.message);
        return "welcome";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/get",method={RequestMethod.GET,RequestMethod.POST})
    public String get(Map<String, Object> model, @RequestParam(value="date") @DateTimeFormat(pattern ="dd-MM-yyyy") LocalDate date) {
        System.out.println("get" + date.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy")));
        return "welcome";
    }

    //this is for testing
    @RequestMapping(value="/get1",method={RequestMethod.GET,RequestMethod.POST})
    public String get1(Map<String, Object> model, @RequestParam(value="date") String date) {
        System.out.println("get1 "+ date);
        return "welcome";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`value`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#date-state-(type=date)) of a `date` input [is **always** in `yyyy-MM-dd` format](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#valid-date-string) (on [browsers that support it](https://caniuse.com/#feat=input-datetime)), regardless of how it's displayed to the user.

Your best option is to update the backend to understand this relatively unambiguous format rather than the more ambiguous formats with the month or day first (`dd/MM/yyyy` as used in the majority of Europe, or `MM/dd/yyyy` as used in most of North America). I believe it would mean this change to your controller class (but Spring MVC isn't my bailiwick):

```
@RequestMapping(value="/get",method={RequestMethod.GET,RequestMethod.POST})
public String get(Map<String, Object> model, @RequestParam(value="date") @DateTimeFormat(pattern ="dd-MM-yyyy") LocalDate date) {
    System.out.println("get" + date.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd")));
    return "welcome";
}
```

You could pre-process the form data client-side to change the format instead, but I wouldn't recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

Write a utility function to handle it.

For example invoke `formatAndReturnDate("30/12/2018","dd/MM/yyyy","yyyy-MM-dd");`

```
public String formatAndReturnDate (String dateValue, String initDateFormat, String endDateFormat) throws ParseException {

    Date dateObj = new SimpleDateFormat(initDateFormat).parse(dateValue);
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(endDateFormat);
    String parsedDate = formatter.format(dateObj);

    return parsedDate;
}
```

Comment: These terrible classes were supplanted years ago by the *java.time* classes with the adoption of JSR 310. See modern solution in the [Answer by Crowder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53338516/642706).